# Rails app routes not available in engine

Tags: view, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm having the opposite problem of other related posts here. I'm using a gem that renders a page that uses the application's layout. That layout works fine in the application otherwise. In that layout is a named path, `login_logout_path`, that causes an `undefined local or method` error.

Here is a snippet of the view code:

```
<%= link_to( ApplicationName + ' Home', root_path ) %> |
<%= link_to('Sign Off', login_logout_path ) %> :
<%= get_session_login.iname %>
```

`root_path` works fine, `logon_logout_path` fails.

On complication might be that the layout above and the `logon_logout_path` is supplied by another gem that contains common code/layouts for the set of web sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer, change

```
login_logout_path
```

with:

```
main_app.login_logout_path
```

and add main_app to all your routes in the application.html.erb that go to your main app

Long answer:
The problem is that engines can have routes with the same name as a route in your main app and work without crashing, if you want to use a route of your main app inside your engine you have to specify it putting

```
main_app.
```

Before the route, and if you want to use a route of your engine in your main app you have to specify it with

```
engineName.example_path
```

The root_path works because your engine has defined a root_path, and it's send you to the root path of the engine, not the one in your app, you can fix it with adding main_app before it too.

Comment: Oddly, I'd found main_app some time after posing this question, but it didn't solve the problem. I tried it again today, and it works. You get the points for the full explanation. Thanks.